In a 2-electron system (such as Helium atom), is the Total Angular Momentum quantum number $j = \ell$?
In a 1-electron system (such as Hydrogen atom), the Total Angular Momentum quantum number $j = \ell \pm s$.
Due to Pauli Exclusion Principle, does that mean a 2-electron system (such as Helium atom) would have $j = \ell$?

Do you mean the ground state of helium?

No.  The Pauli principle is a statement for the entire state, not just the spin part. It is perfectly possible to have $s=0$ - the antisymmetric spin singlet - if the spatial part is symmetric - say $\psi_{100}(\vec r_1)\psi_{100}(\vec r_2)$.
It is also possible to have $s=1$ spin states - the symmetric spin states - if the spatial part is antisymmetric - say
$\psi_{100}(\vec r_1)\psi_{21m}(\vec r_2)- \psi_{21m}(\vec r_1)\psi_{100}(\vec r_2)$.  In this case then the total $j$ is the combination of the $s=1$ for spin and $\ell=1$ for space, so the possible values of $j$ are $2,1,0$.
If the spatial is symmetric, the spin part must be antisymmetric so the product is antisymmetric; conversely, if the spatial part is symmetric the spin part must be antisymmetric.  For 3 or more electrons one can have partially symmetric states for either the spatial or spin part, and they need to combined in a more subtle way but always so the entire state is antisymmetric (for fermions)
Thus the symmetry of the spatial part determines the symmetry of the spin part, but does not necessarily prevent various $j$ to appear.
